# creating a site like p2media.de

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a site like [p2media](http://www.p2media.de) (full Viewport slidable Gallery with content below)

Because I'm a beginner my first step was to create a full Viewport Landingpage (single image) with content below.

with

```
<div class="bodyoben">
</div>

.bodyoben {
    background: url(pics/homescreen.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
/*    overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

the result is exactly what I want. Always centered, not distorted, and 100%height/width.
Now my Question:

Is it possible, to do this also with an < img >?

My first attempt was:

```
<div class="test" style="width:100%;">
        <img src="pics/homescreen.JPG" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

But the result wasn't the same (height was set to auto because of distortion).

My second Question:
Whats the simplest Tutorial for implementing a full viewport slider gallery (with jQuery I guess). I tried some, but wasn't able to implement them well (maybe because I'm a real beginner :).

thx so far, 
sincerly

Comment: First thing your bodyoben CSS declaration is not in STYLE block

Comment: why not use divs in stead of images and use the same technique?

Comment: full width/height slider works the same as any other slide but with other dimensions (height, width, min-height, min-width 100%). It's unclear what you are asking (= define your expectations).

Comment: sorry my mistake, the bodyoben class isn't in the style block (is my forst post, so I made a mistake here :) ) DanFromGermany take a look at www.p2media.de. I want the same layout (fullscreen image, no matter of windowsize with content below). But instead of background images I would prefer to use < img >

Comment: @user3737268 **why** do you like to use `<img />` instead of background images? It's semantically and practically easier and better to use background images.

Comment: I just thought about it, because I'm new to webdesign and wanted to learn it "clean". It isn't a "real" background, because there is no content above the images. A background, in my mind, is just something "behind" the main part, you know what I mean? But if using background-image is the simpler and common way, of course I'll take that route :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with an `img` tag, but only (reliably) with JavaScript.

If you are using the jQuery library, there is a great plugin for this exact purpose, called MaxImage.

**Demo:**

http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/examples/basic.html

**Project Page:**

http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/

For a CSS only version, the best thing you can do (and arguably the easiest) is to use the image as a background for each div and then use the `cover` property of `background-size`, as you seem to already be doing.

In any case, the best article out there that discusses a few real-world options can be found here:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

For reference, one of the options on that link above, without the use of `background-size` or JavaScript, is to do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}

#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

**Protip:**

For better help in the future, I would advise that you ask your question in a more descriptive way to the actual issue you're having. Your current title will attract little attention, because it doesn't state the issue you're having.

Comment: *but only (reliably) with JavaScript* - why that? You can only do this reliably with CSS. `position` and stuff like `z-index` should do the job. But I agree that it's easier and better to use it as background image instead of a blocking image.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I have edit my answer. You can do this with CSS alone quite easily (which I've now explained) but the 'reliably' part comes in when you require that extra logic to make it work cross-browser. It depends on what you want to support, as to your interpretation of what reliably really means.

Comment: thx so far. My next title will be more descriptive. I'll try your code today, but the background-image way seems to be the best (or less code) solution :)